# Understanding Recursion Function

Tags: java, recursion

Recently in class, there was a recursion function that returned an array as either being true or false (sorted or not). However, I had trouble understanding it. The function is:

```
int[] array = { 3, 5, 2, 57, 8, 20 };
int start=0;
boolean sorted = sorted( array, start, array.length );
System.out.print( "array: ");
for ( int i=0 ; i<array.length ; ++i ) System.out.print( array[i] + " " );
                                             
if (sorted) System.out.println(" is sorted" );  
                                           
else System.out.println( "is not sorted" ); 

static boolean sorted(int array[], int i, int count ) { 
        if (count == 1 || count == 0)  return true; 
        if (array[count - 1] < array[count - 2]) return false;
        return sorted(array, i-1, --count);
    }
```

What is happening in the method and how is the recursion working? What does the variable count do if there is already an integer i? Why must it be equal to 0(or null) and 1? Why are the variables different for when you initialize "sorted" in the main method and for the sorted method? I believe some of the additional questions I asked may be redundant or unnecessary if I knew how the whole method worked. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: The `sorted` method has a unwanted parameter `i` which is never used.

Comment: Null and zero are totally different things in java.

Comment: The magic happens in the sorted() method. The first line returns true if the length of the array if equal to 0 or 1 (an array of that length is always sorted). The second line returns false if the last element is less than the second to last element (that means the array is not sorted). The last line just returns the value of sorted for a shorter version of this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to the forum! :) Indubitably, recursion is something that's really difficult to come to grips with, but if you have learned about stack - as a part of the memory - you can understand recursion more easily. [This](https://predictivehacks.com/a-comparison-between-iteration-reduce-recursion-memoization-in-r/) article might appear useful in investigating what exactly happens in these types of algorithms.

The code might not be written in Java, but the syntax itself will be fairly understandable. I suggest you skip the memoization part - since it is more advanced and you can learn it later -, but the factorial code and the image are really self-explanatory.

You could also practice and write these algorithms and I agree: debugging is excessively useful if you don't understand something.

Finally, let me add some practical pieces of advice in the future for coding in Java:

- Auto-format your code (the hotkeys are different in every major IDE's, but they definitely exist)
- Avoid C-style coding when declaring arrays:
  instead of

  ```
  int array[]
  ```

  , Java devs tend to do it in the following way:

  ```
  int[] array
  ```

(Fun fact about multidimensional arrays: int[][] array, int array[][] and int[] array[] (!) work too.)

- Last, but not least, do not miss curly braces also if there is only one statement in that particular block of code.

These are only coding conventions, though that code is syntactically alright, as you might have already seen it.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The `sorted` method could just be:

```java
static boolean sorted(int array[], int count) { 
    if (count == 1 || count == 0) {
        // If the array has no elements or if it just has a single element,
        // then it means that the array is sorted.
        return true;
    }

    if (array[count - 1] < array[count - 2]) {
        // If an element is less than the previous element,
        // then the array is not sorted.
        return false;
    }

    // check rest of the array.
    return sorted(array, count-1);
}
```

I would suggest you to debug through the whole code so that you could get a better picture of what is happening.